# questions on move up method in Zipper

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, zipper

I am reading the [Zipper article](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Zipper) in Haskell Wiki
and I can't understand the `up` method defined as:

```
data Tree a = Fork (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a

data Cxt a = Top | L (Cxt a) (Tree a) | R (Tree a) (Cxt a)

type Loc a = (Tree a, Cxt a)

up :: Loc a -> Loc a
up (t, L c r) = (Fork t r, c)
up (t, R l c) = (Fork l t, c)
```

In the pattern `up (t, L c r)`, `t` is the subtree with focus, `c` is the context with a hole at current focus, when moving up, why `c` doesn't move up but still referenced to the old context? Shouldn't the focus also go up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
up (t, L c r) = (Fork t r, c)
```

not `c` is the current context, but `L c r` is. The context describes a path from your current tree to the root. A context of form `L c r` originates from descending into a left subtree, so in order to go up one layer, we have to combine it with the corresponding right subtree `r`. The `c` is the *remaining* path up to the root, and therefore becomes the new context.

Let's look at a small example: assume you have a tree that looks like this:

```
   *
  / \
 /   \
/ \ / \
1 2 3 4
```

It would be represented using the `Tree` type as

```
tree = Fork (Fork (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2))
            (Fork (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4))
```

Now the location where `Leaf 3` is selected in the tree looks as follows:

```
loc3 = (Leaf 3, L (R (Fork (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) Top) (Leaf 4))
```

Note that the context here is of the form

```
L c (Leaf 4)
```

indicating that on the path from your current node up you are in the left subtree of
the parent node, and the corresponding right subtree is `Leaf 4`. The `c` is the context
for the remaining steps, in this case that the tree `Fork (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4)` is actually
the right subtree of the complete tree.

Comment: I asked the same question on SO two years ago and I was not convinced by your answer then, now I accept both. Thanks.